# How to change the ip address of a computer in Windows?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, ip

How to change the IP address of a computer in Windows? Is there any available API?

Using **[AddIPAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365801(v=vs.85).aspx)** function, I have added the IP address and the newly IP address is successfully showing in the network connection details but failed to change in the **tcp/ip** table .So please suggest some way out.

Comment: please leave any suggestion

Comment: Why you ask the question if you show no interest on an answer?

Comment: @Imran: Do you have an interest to answers on the question?

Answer (score 4):

Try [EnableStatic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390383(v=vs.85).aspx) and [SetGateways](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393301(v=vs.85).aspx) of WMIObject [Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394217(v=vs.85).aspx). The methods allows to configure the computer to use specific static IP address.

To tell the trust, one needn't set some static IP address in the most cases. One gets IP address from DHCP. One can use [IpReleaseAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366056(v=vs.85).aspx) and [IpRenewAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366057(v=vs.85).aspx) of [iphlpapi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366073(v=vs.85).aspx) in the case. I should remark that there is *undocumented* function `SetAdapterIpAddress` exported by `IpHlpApi.dll`, but I think that the usage of *documented* WMI method `EnableStatic` is better.

Answer (score 1):

To change IP and default gateway:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
 System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
 startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
 startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
 startInfo.Arguments = "netsh int ip set address \"local area connection\" static 192.168.0.101      255.255.255.0 192.168.0.254 1 ";
 process.StartInfo = startInfo;
 process.Start();
```

Comment: Since @peter-o asked about C++, not C#, he could use `system` or `_spawnlp` or `Createprocess` instead... but the conversion should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Quick google search to find this [link](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Your-IP-Address-(Windows)). Dont know if its what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Please look [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/103190/change-your-ip-address-from-the-command-prompt/) if you want to change the setting from the command line (can be scripted). Or you might want to use Powershell using [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/02/28/use-powershell-to-configure-static-ip-and-dns-settings.aspx) example.