# Set ip settings from cpp(Qt)

Tags: c++, windows-ce, regedit

Its really hard going to code to save the ip settings(RegSetValueEx()) from cpp(By registry editing of WinCe).
Its issue about encoding of string(which I parse to BYTE* and if I use hardcoded string,parsed it to same BYTE* it supports)
Anybody can support for coding, will be good.Otherwise , please show me the different routes if you can.
(Like batch file(setting ip with ipconfig) to execute from cpp).

```
HKEY hKey;
int res = RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"Comm\\ENET1\\Parms\\TcpIp", 0, KEY_WRITE, &hKey);
const BYTE* data = (BYTE*)text;
long ret = RegSetValueEx(hKey,L"IpAddress",0,REG_MULTI_SZ,data,16);
RegCloseKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE);
```

It should save ip on WinCe from cpp.

1. By batch file executing from cpp.
2. Registry editing from cpp.
3. Or any other method.

Comment: don't know if this'll work on wince: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25862904/how-to-change-the-ip-address-of-a-computer-in-windows

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.